# Center div beside textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, center, vertical-alignment

How can I center the text beside the textarea?
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/47NyA/

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an image of what you want to achieve? Thanks :)

Comment: @shub - is working for you ????

Comment: No sorry this doesn't work for me. It centers the text horizontally and not vertically.

Comment: @Umer Hayat I uploaded an image.

Comment: btw, whats wrong with Arthur Wulf White's solution http://jsfiddle.net/47NyA/7/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with This

```
<div style="display:table">     
    <label for="textarea">Description</label><br>  
    <textarea id="textarea" style="display: table-cell;"></textarea>
    <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; width:100px; text-align:center; border:#f00 1px solid;">Text</div>
</div>
```

also check in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47NyA/9/)

Answer (score 2):

Pure css

http://jsfiddle.net/47NyA/7/

This could work for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* style here */

        div#main{
            position:relative;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }

        textarea{
        }

        div.right{
            position:absolute;
            top:45%;
            right:0px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <div class="right">
            TEXT
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript solution:

This could work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/47NyA/4/

Let me know if it does the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           // set init (default) state   
           var t = jQuery('#text_area');

           t.data('x', t.outerWidth());
           t.data('y', t.outerHeight());

           t.mouseup(function(){
              var th = jQuery(this);
              if (th.outerWidth()!= th.data('x') || th.outerHeight() != th.data('y'))

              // set new height/width
              th.data('x', th.outerWidth());
              th.data('y', th.outerHeight());
              $("#center_text").css("margin-top", (th.outerHeight()/2 - 20) + "px");
           });


        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would like have the solution with CSS. Any idea?

Comment: Hi :) The first solution is actually pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to get height of textarea, and update the line-height of the  on the right, set text align to be center